# How to detect screen resolution change in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, screen-resolution

The question is simple. How to detect screen resolution change in Delphi ?

Comment: Look a message having something to do with system metrics. E.g. WM_SYSTEMMETRICSCHANGE

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recognize when number, position, or resolution of monitors has changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004051/how-to-recognize-when-number-position-or-resolution-of-monitors-has-changed)

Comment: @David - That one is now marked duplicate of this one (wonder what happens if they recurse..).

Comment: @David, Sertac: The other one has been closed, so this one should *not* be closed. Also, I think it is good that the old one is closed and not this one, since this one has a better answer.

Comment: I agree. The diamond mod Shog got it right.

Comment: Being the OP of the other question, I do have to say this one does have a better answer, and by the same person.

Comment: Duplicates are very useful to find the answer by any search string.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You only need to detect the [`WM_DISPLAYCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145210(v=vs.85).aspx) message.

For instance,

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
private
protected
  procedure WMDisplayChange(var Message: TWMDisplayChange);
    message WM_DISPLAYCHANGE;
  { Private declarations }

public
  { Public declarations }
end;

...

procedure TForm1.WMDisplayChange(var Message: TWMDisplayChange);
begin
  ShowMessageFmt('The screen resolution has changed to %d×%d×%d.',
    [Message.Width, Message.Height, Message.BitsPerPixel]);
end;
```

[image: Sample screenshot]