# How to detect screen resolution change in Delphi FireMonkey FMX

Tags: delphi, winapi, firemonkey, screen-resolution

How can I detect screen resolution change in Delphi FireMonkey / FMX

This solution for VCL has already been posted
[How to detect screen resolution change in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772588/how-to-detect-screen-resolution-change-in-delphi)

That solution works well for VCL, but I am looking for a solution for FireMonkey.

Comment: For which platforms?

Comment: If you are interested only on windows platform then the linked answer should also bee good enough as it relyies on intercepting Windows message that is send at screen resolution change by the OS itself. I'm not sure if same would work on other platforms.

Comment: Windows api code won't work on Android. Use the onresize method of the form on Android.

Comment: @nolaspeaker Can you even adjust screen resolution on android devices? Isn't screen resolution of all android devices fixed to the screen resolution of physical screen?

Comment: Yes. But differentAndroid devices have different screen metrics, so you might want to determine the height and width of the screen for control element positioning, especially after the device is rotated.

Comment: The linked solution will work similarly in FireMonkey on Windows, too.  You just need an `HWND` that can receive the `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` message. You can use the RTL's `AllocateHWnd()` for that, or you can use `SetWindowLongPtr()`/`SetWindowSubclass()` to hook the `HWND` returned by `FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND(MyForm)` or `FMX.Platform.Win.WindowHandleToPlatform(MyForm.Handle).Wnd`

Comment: @nolaspeaker When you change rotation of mobile device the screen resolution doesn't change only the orientation parameter does. And then it is up to the specific application to handle that appropriately and render its application contents in correct orientation. Firemonkey does provide needed functionality for this even including the ability to design two separate form layouts one for landscape and one for portrait orientation.

Comment: What was the reason for your original question then? Why do you want to know how to get screen resolution on Android?

Comment: Remy -  I think you are on the right track here but I dont know how to complete it.

This is my test case so far

uses WinApi.Messages; 

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure WMDisplayChange(var Message: TWMDisplayChange);
    message WM_DISPLAYCHANGE;
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.WMDisplayChange(var Message: TWMDisplayChange);
begin
  ShowMessageFmt(
            'The screen resolution has changed to %d×%d×%d.'
           ,[Message.Width, Message.Height, Message.BitsPerPixel]
    );
end;

end.

Comment: My last comment was difficult to read so I have posted my test case for FMX using Delphi 10.4 based on the VCL code ... but not working for FMX

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ezmbdcco7bfb7ui/AAAkZHgysSmefCcJ55dC1VBSa?dl=0

I appreciate any tips anyone can offer on this issue

Comment: This might help to get the HWND for the application

FMX.Platform.Win.ApplicationHWND

Answer (score 0):

Try this codes. First add FMX.Platform to uses:

```
function ScreenResolutionChanged(old, new: string): Boolean;
begin
  if old <> new then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := False;
end;

function getScreenSize: string;
var
  ScreenSvc: IFMXScreenService;
  ScreenSize: TSize;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXScreenService,
    IInterface(ScreenSvc)) then
  begin
    Result := Format('Resolution: %fX%f', [ScreenSvc.GetScreenSize.X,
        ScreenSvc.GetScreenSize.Y]);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  oldScreenSize, newScreenSize: string;
begin
  oldScreenSize := getScreenSize;
  Sleep(10000); // Wait 10 Sec
  newScreenSize := getScreenSize;
  if ScreenResolutionChanged(newScreenSize, oldScreenSize) then
    ShowMessage('Screen Resolution Changed ' + #10#13 + oldScreenSize + #10#13 +
      newScreenSize)
  else
    ShowMessage('Screen Resolution NOT Changed ' + #10#13 + oldScreenSize +
      #10#13 + newScreenSize);
end;
```